# WKRefreshBackgroundTask cleanupStorage Error attempting to reach file

Tags: swift, xcode, background, apple-watch-complication, watchos-4

Whats this error I get when making a URLBGTask in WatchOS4 on the Simulator?

`2017-09-28 16:05:26.452999+0900 MiFollowers WatchKit Extension[4628:4012814] [bg_app_refresh] -[WKRefreshBackgroundTask cleanupStorage]_block_invoke:213: Error attempting to reach file:///Users/ryuuzaki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2E4D6389-93B7-4542-B07F-9A02C720B9AF/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/FA4415DF-D984-4394-80B9-EDA199AB587E/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktaskapp_(null): Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “bktaskapp_(null)” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/ryuuzaki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2E4D6389-93B7-4542-B07F-9A02C720B9AF/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/FA4415DF-D984-4394-80B9-EDA199AB587E/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktaskapp_(null), NSFilePath=/Users/ryuuzaki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2E4D6389-93B7-4542-B07F-9A02C720B9AF/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/FA4415DF-D984-4394-80B9-EDA199AB587E/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktaskapp_(null), NSUnderlyingError=0x79b0e340 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

Any of you bright minds out there know what all this means?

Comment: Could you resolve this problem?

Comment: Not yet, until now, I have spent months with Apple Developer Support since I have paid for the Developer Account, but they are yet to provide a straight answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this too. Drove me nuts for the last two days.

I'm still not sure if it is a bug or "feature" to require you to use the `userInfo` property. This is happening if you don't get the `userInfo` property from the background refresh task in the `handle(_ backgroundTasks)` method. Any access of the property works. A simple workaround one to get rid of the error is to schedule your next background refresh in the `handle` method with `backgroundTask.userInfo` in the `userInfo:` parameter which just keeps assigning `nil` to the next task.

```
WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: refreshDate, userInfo: backgroundTask.userInfo) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print ("Background task error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Of course this workaround means you won't be able to use `userInfo`. Better code might be to stick something in there such as the scheduling date or an identifier for the task, or a dictionary of `[String:Any]` for both.

Comment: Thank you for this. Such a bizarre problem. I'm not sure if it was doing any harm, but I'm thankful I don't have to see it anymore when debugging. The way I went about it is simply creating a class-level variable called userInfoAccess, and then just doing  userInfoAccess = backgroundTask.userInfo  in my handle background tasks loop. This way I can still use the background refresh userInfo.